# How can I write a `view/getter` function to see the results of another function

Tags: solidity, arrays, function, view

This is my code to remove an element from an array using "shifting method" :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Arrayelement{
    //context :
    /* let an array be : [1,2,3,4] .... we want to remove 2
    what we do is , shift elements startng from 2 towards left
    i.e. the array will become [1,3,4,4] and then pop out last 4 */

    uint[] public arr;

    function remove(uint _index) public {
        require(_index < arr.length, "Index out of bounds");
        for(uint i = _index ; i < arr.length-1; i++){
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
        }
        arr.pop();
    }

    function testremove() public {
        arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
        remove(2);
        assert(arr[0] == 1);
        assert(arr[1] == 2);
        assert(arr[2] == 4);
        assert(arr[3] == 5);
        assert(arr.length == 4);
    }

    function get() public view {
           }
}
```

`get()` function is what I want to write so that I can see the results of the steps in the `testremove()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a an `arr()` function to inspect the array, one row at a time. This is the scalable pattern. You can also make a function that returns the whole array. Caution with that because it doesn't scale.

Not sure if this just a contrived example, or if there is a goal in mind. Have a look over here: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity).

Deletion is a little counter-intuitive in blockchains. It often isn't needed and it is never completely effective. An additional challenge is to create a process that has the same cost at any scale which this iterative process does not achieve. This explainer unfolds a pattern with an example. The pattern is used in OpenZeppelin EnumerableSet.sol: https://medium.com/robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-1-824ffa69509a

Here's your getter:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Arrayelement{

    uint[] public arr;

    function set() public {
        for(uint i=0; i<10; i++) {
            arr.push(i+1);
        }
    }

    function get() public view returns(uint[] memory array) {
        return arr;
    }

    function remove(uint _index) public {
        require(_index < arr.length, "Index out of bounds");
        for(uint i = _index ; i < arr.length-1; i++){
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
        }
        arr.pop();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.